# Apache won't follow symlinks even with permissions set

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I can't get apache to follow symlinks outside the web root directory, even though permissions look OK and FollowSymLinks is on. The details are below.

I have two world-readable text files: `/tmp/hello` and `/var/www/html/hello`.
Also in webroot I have symlinks to both those files. Both seem fine.

```
$ ll /tmp
drwxrwxrwt. 27 root   root       4096 Jul  8 13:55 ./
dr-xr-xr-x. 23 root   root       4096 Jul  4 23:24 ../
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root          6 Jul  8 13:55 hello

$ ll /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root   root   4096 Jul  8 13:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root   root   4096 Apr  4 12:57 ../
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root     20 Jul  8 14:03 hello
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   root      5 Jul  8 14:04 link-local -> /var/www/html/hello
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root   root     10 Jul  8 13:56 link-tmp -> /tmp/hello

$ cat /var/www/html/link-local 
/VAR/WWW/HTML/HELLO

$ cat /var/www/html/link-tmp 
/TMP/HELLO
```

Apache can follow the link to the web root:

```
$ curl http://localhost/link-local
/VAR/WWW/HTML/HELLO
```

But Apache won't follow the symlink to `/tmp/`:

```
$ curl http://localhost/link-tmp
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /hellolink on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

This is on CentOS 6; http runs as user apache, group apache.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: After further experimentation, I suspect the problem is to do with some sort of permission problem on the /tmp/hello file. But I still don't understand the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It looks as if SELinux is the culprit:

> The -Z switch will work with most utilities to show SELinux security
>   contexts (e.g, 'ls -Z', 'ps axZ' etc).

```
$ ll -Z /var/www/html/hello
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html/hello

$ ll -Z /tmp/hello
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 /tmp/hello
```

The two target files have different types (`httpd_sys_content_t` vs `user_tmp_t`), which explains the difference in accessibility.

The [SELinux page at centos.org](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) explains the `-Z` switch and much, much more.

Comment: For myself, SELinux was disabled, but the status showed permissive mode. After a reboot, the status was "disabled" and my original symlink config worked as before. All of my Unix permissions were correct, but apparently a mismatched SE security context even in permissive mode will cause Apache to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting FollowSymlinks in an .htaccess file? or in a `<Directory>` block?

[Apache 2.2 Options documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) suggests that FollowSymlinks will only work in these contexts - could you post the relevant config?

(posting as an answer due to insufficient points to comment)

Comment: FollowSymLinks is set in a `<Directory>` block. Note that Apache does follow the `link-local` symlink, but not the `link-tmp` symlink in the same directory.

Comment: It's perhaps a shot in the dark: do you have SELinux enabled? That could be causing what you're seeing... also, have you tried achieving the same thing using an Alias directive? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside

Comment: it appears that SELinux is enabled (`getenforce` results in `Enforcing`). I will have to do some experimenting to see if that's the cause.

Comment: I'm sure I could use an Alias to do this, but for me a symlinks is clearer and more transparent - a simple `ls -l` will tell you where files are being serves from, rather than having to go looking through httpd.conf. Also I just wanted to know why the symlink doesn't work! :)

Comment: It's almost certainly due to SELinux being enabled - once you've disabled it, you *may* also need to reboot, since the file system may have been mounted with security contexts enabled, and simply setting selinux permissive or disabled may not clear down the file ACLs - I've had that happen to be before, and only a reboot will fix this. (In spite of online resources/docs suggesting using setenfore to set this on the fly)

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I've been working on a symlink problem for hours. SELinux was disabled, but the status showed permissive mode. But like you suggested a reboot was necessary to get the status to "disabled." After the reboot, my original symlink config worked as before.